# jQuery vertical tabs which remain on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a jquery tab that remembers which tab was last when the page refresh. I have found the fiddle below and adapted to my needs in php but i am novice with jave script and i don`t fully understand how it works so i can not figure it out hou could i do in javascript or javascript combined with php to remember what tab was when page refreshed.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#a">Tab A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#b">Tab B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#c">Tab C</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#d">Tab D</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="a">
        Content of A
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        Content of B
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        Content of C
    </div>
    <div id="d">
        Content of D
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#tabs')
    .tabs()
    .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/nn2Qw/)

Comment: add tab id to Cookies [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: off the top of my head, you need to use cookies which implementing and dealing with cookies might be a bit complicated if you're not familiar with jQuery

Comment: could you please do this in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set tab's or link's  hash in your URL, **then jQuery UI will do automaticaly**, heres your jquery code example

```
$(function(){
    $('#tabs')
        .tabs()
        .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
    $("#tabs>ul>li>a").on('click', function(event) {
        window.location.hash = event.target.hash;
    })
});
```

> **NOTE:** This will not work in jsfiddle

Comment: i did not see the note and i checked in fiddle (: Thank you! It works exactly how i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

When the anchor  is clicked, add a fragment identifier to the URL e.g. http://example.com/#b. Then on page load you can check for this and show the correct tab.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates it but doesn't work on fiddle because it needs to change the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/rgRp3/5/

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    var selected = window.location.hash;
    if (selected != '') {
        $('#a').hide();
        $(selected).show();
    }
});
```